# Javascript remoting not hitting apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I'm trying to call an Apex function from a Visualforce page, but my Apex function isn't getting hit. What am I doing wrong?

I have this

```
ct_4_sf.RecordingTest.saveRecording(
    paths,
    function(data){
        console.log('data is ',data);
    }
);
```

Which is supposed to call this:

```
public with sharing class RecordingTest {

    @RemoteAction
    public static String saveRecording(String data) {
        System.debug('hit save recording' + data);
        return Connector.saveRecording(data);
    }
}
```

But the `System.debug` line never gets hit.

I've also tried it this way

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{ct_4_sf.RecordingTest.saveRecording}',
    paths,
    function(data){
        console.log('data is ',data);
    }
);
```

with the same result.

For this method, using `!$RemoteAction` instead of, or in front of  `ct_4_sf` gives me compilation errors. Removing `ct_4_sf`(which is the namespace under Setup > Create > Packages), from the first method doesn't help.

I'm not getting any errors in the console or anywhere else.

Comment: 1) You should probably make `RemoteAction` methods global. 2) Are you sure your log levels are high enough?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the prefix `ct_4_sf`? Using `RecordingTest.saveRecording( params )` in the JavaScript of your VF page should work as you don't appear to have a namespace to deal with.

Comment: @AdrianLarson setting the class and method to global didn't help. Yes, I confirmed that my log levels are high enough.

Comment: @MarkPond I removed `ct_4_sf` prefix, which is the namespace defined in Setup > Create > Namespace Prefix, and that didn't help

Comment: What is the data type for the `paths` var you are passing in? If it is not `String` that could be the cause...

Comment: @AdrianLarson good call. I was sending an object. I stringified it, but still the problem persists

Comment: Do you have any other javascript in the page that is loaded after the remoting script that may be conflicting or overwriting the `ct_4_sf` object/namespace? i.e. `var ct_4_sf = {};`

Comment: @MarkPond Nope. In fact, `ct_4_sf` isn't even in my file at all now, since you said I didn't need it

Comment: Did you check in console whether any error is coming. If the data types that you are passing doesnt match, it may not hit apex. but it will throw error in browser console.

Comment: @Victor Yes. There are no errors in the browser console.

Comment: I would try putting line by line console.log() statements in javascript method and find till what line it is executing. Then further debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this line right here:

```
'{ct_4_sf.RecordingTest.saveRecording}',
```

You should be using the $RemoteAction merge value, like this:

```
'{!$RemoteAction.RecordingTest.saveRecording}',
```

This automatically takes care of your namespacing problems, too.

Your controller won't be available unless you include it as a controller or extension on the page. You don't automatically get all remote actions for free.

Comment: From the OP: "For this method, using `!$RemoteAction` instead of, or in front of  `ct_4_sf` gives me compilation errors." He already tried your solution.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I forgot to mention that the page must reference the controller or extension where the remoteaction lives, or it won't compile/resolve $RemoteAction, nor will it include it in the page's script (so it can't be called).

Comment: How do I "include my controller as a controller or extension on the page?", if that's a step I'm missing?

Comment: @Houseman `<apex:page standardController="..." extensions="RecordingTest" ...>` or `<apex:page controller="RecordingTest" ...>`. Also, if you need it as an extension, you'll need to add `public RecordingTest(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { }` to your class.

Comment: @sfdcfox Good catch. I forgot about that part because my JS is in a `Static Resource` so I didn't look at the `page` itself.

Comment: I added `controller="RecordingTest"` to my `<apex:page`, which wasn't there previously,  but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Houseman Does $RemoteAction compile now? Do not include the namespace, it's automatically taken care of.

Comment: Oh, I got it after I added `ct_4_sf` back in.  `$RemoteAction` also compiles, and doing it either way now works. I guess the crucial part is having  the reference to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `event` to your callback function. Usually when I do remoting, it looks something like:

```
MyExtension.remoteMethod(
    param1, param2, function (result, event) {
        if (event.status) {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log(event);
        }
    }
);
```

Also make sure in your `page` tag you have `extensions="MyExtension"`. Not sure if you are using a standard or custom controller, but your `page` tag should look something like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="RecordingTest">
```

Comment: That didn't help.

Comment: What are you seeing in the console? Anything?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the console

Comment: So you are not hitting your callback... Have you tried any debugging in the JS method that calls the `RemoteAction`? Maybe we need that context to help.

Comment: I have a `console.log` right above my remote call, and that gets hit. The only other meaningful place I can add a log is when the function returns, where logs already are.